# Run a specific SQL Server job step from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a job with 5 steps that are scheduled to run after each other.

I want to have a stored procedure where a user can execute the stored procedure and give the step number as a parameter.

Only this job step then will be executed and no further steps.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct support to start a job at a given step and run no further steps.

As a workaround, you could read the step command from [`msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobsteps-transact-sql) and run that directly.